# correct usage of "in bulk"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

Our software works with contract management.
Let's say item A is part of the contract. Our system has two ways of adding
an item A to a contract:

1. A special tab within the contract window that deals with defining
   and adding item A. This requires opening the contract and navigating to the
   tab, which for several contracts can be a hassle, and therefore we created
   option b which is:
2. An "outside" window, through which you can specify some base
   values, create item A's which all include those values by default, and then
   link them to their respective contracts. **The point is to save time and not
   have to enter each contract to create its item A, rather to be able to do it
   "from above".**

My inclination was to call this *Bulk Item A Creation* (for the sake of the
example) - because it is what one would use if he had to make a bunch of
item A's and wanted to save time. **But** the process itself doesn't create item
A's in bulk, rather it lets me create a lot in an easier way.

Does this pass for a "bulk process"?

And if not - what is a better choice?

Sample sentence:

> To create item A's quickly and efficiently, use the _________________ process.

Answer (score 1):

You can call it *batch processing*.

> Batch processing is the execution of a series of jobs in a program on a computer without manual intervention (non-interactive).
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_processing)

In your example, the batch process populates the default values for the items.

You add a further stipulation in your question:

> But the process itself doesn't create item A's in bulk, rather it lets me create a lot in an easier way.

If by this you mean that no items are created, then you are *initialising* or *setting* the defaults.

> **Initialise** *verb*
>   1 *often be initialized to) Set to the value or put in the condition appropriate to the start of an operation.
>   ‘the counter is initialized to one’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/initialize)

Here's an example:

> *Setting defaults*
>   When working with DataTables over multiple pages it is often useful to set the initialisation defaults to common values (for example you might want to set dom to a common value so all tables get the same layout).
>   [- datatables.net](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/defaults.html)

In your sample sentence, you can say:

- To create item A's quickly and efficiently, use the *initialisation* process.

However, with this particular phrasing, it would probably be better to say:

- To create item A's quickly and efficiently, use the *prepopulation* process.

> **Prepopulate** *verb*
>   (computing) To populate (form fields, a database, etc.) in advance.
>   [- yourdictionary.com](http://www.yourdictionary.com/prepopulate)

Comment: IMO *batch processing* is even more problematic than @DAE had with *bulk process*. He seems to be describing an assisted methodology to do one thing at a time.

Comment: @RichF It occurred to me that DAE only wanted to initialise the defaults, rather than create the items. I've added that to my answer.

Comment: @RichF and Lawrence, thanks for your input - I like this direction.

Answer (score -1):

For your blank: preset process, scripted process, simplified process, automated process. There are a lot of options.

More generally, a popular terminology used to be (still is?) **wizard** -- for your situation, maybe either *Contract Modification Wizard* or *Item Creation Wizard* would work. (I always thought *wizard* sounded hokey, but its meaning was clear. That's kind of the point.)

I agree that "bulk process" is not a good fit since it is not meant to do multiple changes at once.

Comment: Well, it's not a wizard - it's just a pre-emptive stage that causes certain fields to already be populated when you perform the process.

Comment: @DAE *Item Creation Template* then?